# JavaScript - New Nested Object From Current Object Keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

When working with an object like the following, what is the most effective way to build a new object based on the current object's keys? The keys serve as the reference to where it should be in the new object - `activityName1` would be equal to the first element `name` of the new `activities` nested array, `activityName2` equal to the second element `name` of the array & so on.

```
const obj = {
  activityName1: "Bingo",
  activityName2: "Bazinga",
  activityType1: "Dog",
  activityType2: "Term",
  description: "Games are fun.",
  name: "Patty"
};
```

Desired object:

```
const newObj = {
  activities: [
   {name: "Bingo", type: "Dog"},
   {name: "Bazinga", type: "Term"}
  ],
  description: "Games are fun.",
  name: "Patty"
};
```

My initial thoughts were to use `reduce` & `Object.assign`, but the building of the new object returns only a single key/value pair:

```
Object.keys(variables).reduce((obj, key) => {
  if (key.includes('activity')) {
    return Object.assign(obj, {
     [key[key.length - 1]]: { activities: { [key]: variables[key] } } });
  }
  return obj;
}, {});
```

Results in a new `activities` array like:

```
[
  1: {activities: {type: "Dog"},
  2: {activities: {type: "Term"}
]
```

Comment: is `activities` in your expected output meant to be an array? Currently its not valid

Comment: Yes - `activities` was meant to be an array - question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only use of mapping is to look for those keys that start `activityName` and use those to build up your array of `activities`. You can reuse the key replacing `activityName` with `activityType` to get the associated type.

```js
const obj = {
  activityName1: "Bingo",
  activityName2: "Bazinga",
  activityType1: "Dog",
  activityType2: "Term",
  description: "Games are fun.",
  name: "Patty"
};

var result = {
   activities: Object.keys(obj).filter(k => k.startsWith("activityName")).map(k => ({
       name: obj[k],
       type:obj[k.replace("activityName","activityType")]
   })),
   description: obj.description,
   name: obj.name
}

console.log(result);
```